# my pytesseract is not working(i need help)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-tesseract, pyautogui

my plan is to make a bot that will answer a bot on messenger

the messenger bot messages are randomized number or a math questionaire bot

so i want to make a bot that will answer the messenger bots qustions

i made a code like this:

```
import pyautogui
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
```

i want to take screenshot every 10 seconds

```
pyautogui.sleep(2)
```

sleep for two seconds to give me time to switch from pycharm to messenger

```
pyautogui.screenshot('x_value.png', confidence=0.8)
img = Image.open('x_value.png')
img = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(img)
```

[here is the taken screenshot by my bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFag2.png)

here is the result:

```
Tee oxHj
```

i tried resizing the image using tuple but I still get the wrong result....i hope ypu guys help me so i can improve my skills....thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I inverted the image. But I wasn't able to use .png format so I tried in .jpg format and it worked. You can try this.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

img = Image.open('f1.jpg')
img = ImageOps.invert(img)
img = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(img)
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: It really did work! I am Very happy cause the bot now understands the input of the Messenger bot....Thank You Very Much!